# Update SQL Server statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column data with length 11 characters of type `varchar`. I want to change to 10 characters with condition: change 4 characters to 3 characters base on condition if begin 4 characters is '0169' and then change to '039'.

Example:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (SomeCol VARCHAR(11));

INSERT INTO @Table (SomeCol) 
VALUES ('01691234567'), ('01692234567'), ('01693234567'), 
       ('01694234567'), ('01695234567'), ('11691234567'), 
       ('11692234567'), ('11693234567'), ('11694234567'), 
       ('11695234567');
```

Expected output:

| SomeCol |
| --- |
| 0391234567 |
| 0392234567 |
| 0393234567 |
| 0394234567 |
| 0395234567 |
| 11691234567 |
| 11692234567 |
| 11693234567 |
| 11694234567 |
| 11695234567 |

Comment: The input given as an example '01691234567' should not be transformed to '0391234567' right? because it does not start with '0160' as per your initial question.

Comment: Try the following if you are still interested in replacing characters

```UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = '039' + SUBSTRING(YourColumn, 5, LEN(YourColumn) - 4)
WHERE LEN(YourColumn) = 11 AND LEFT(YourColumn, 4) = '0160';```

Answer (score 0):

The following UPDATE statement help you to change column values to 10 characters if the value begins with '0169' using CASE statement.
You can include additional WHEN clause inside the CASE statement if you want to change the column value based on any other similar condition.

```
UPDATE @Table SET SomeCol = CASE LEFT(SomeCol,4) 
                                WHEN '0169' THEN '039'+RIGHT(SomeCol,LEN(SomeCol)- 4) 
                                ELSE SomeCol 
                            END
FROM @Table
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).